# [Vue warn]: Duplicate keys detected:

Tags: vue.js

[Vue warn]: Duplicate keys detected: '65535'. This may cause an update error.

found in

```
---> <Board> at src/components/Board.vue
       <App> at src/App.vue
         <Root>
```

this code

```
<div class="listWrapper" v-for="list in board.lists" :key="list.pos" :data-list-id="list.id">
                            <List :data="list"></List>
                        </div>
```

and

```
const targetCard = {
                id: el.dataset.cardId * 1,
                listId: wrapper.dataset.listId * 1,
                pos : 65535
            }
```

I got this error. There seems to be an error in this code. How to solve it?

Comment: Use ```v-for="list in board.lists" ``` as ```v-for="(list, index) in board.lists" and provide ```:key=index``` if you don't have ```list.pos``` as a unique value.

Answer (score 2):

your `:key="list.pos"` is `pos:65535` so you have error

use different key will be ok

the key will make your dom update with data is update, so should make the `:key` unmatched.

Answer (score 0):

`list.pos` isn't unique for each item you're looping through. In order for Vue to keep track of your items when `board.lists` changes internally, each item needs to have a unique identifier. This is very important if you're going to be adding/moving/removing items in the array.

- If the items in `board.lists` come from a database, you could use `:key="list.id"` (or whichever key the database uses to distinguish the different items). This removes the error, and causes the least rerenders when `board.lists` updates.
- If your item doesn't have an id (or another key that is guaranteed to be unique), you could use the index method provided by the other answers. `v-for="(list, listidx) in board.lists" :key="'list-' + listidx"`.

The index method can cause items to rerender unnecessarily. When the first item
is removed from the array for example, the index (and thus the key)
changes for every item after that, causing the entire list to be
rerendered. Depending on the size of your list and the markup of your
list items, this can be deadly to your app's performance.

Answer (score -1):

You should use unique ids in v-for key. A simple solution is to use index as your v-for key.

```
<div class="listWrapper" v-for="(list,index) in board.lists" :key="index" :data-list-id="list.id">
```

Comment: Using an index causes unnecessary rerenders when an item changes place in the array. It works in terms of removing the error, but it would be much better to use a unique identifier from the database if available (e.g. listId or cardId), as that is not dependent on the order of the array.

Comment: that's totally correct but if there is not unique ids in the database, this is the only way

Comment: He could use :key="list.id" instead of index